# Find and replace in a specific column and not entire sheet

Tags: vba

I have the below code which looks for specific words from a table and replaces them to something else which is also in a table.

However, it replaces everything in the whole sheet and i actually only want it to work on a specific column (D:D)

Can anyone help?

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Integer
Dim rplcList As Integer
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant
    'Create variable to point to your table


 Set tbl = Worksheets("Tables").ListObjects("Word")
        'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
  Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
  myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)
        'Designate Columns for Find/Replace data
  fndList = 1
  rplcList = 2
        'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2)
        'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook (skip sheet with table in it)
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> tbl.Parent.Name Then
          sht.Cells.Replace What:=myArray(fndList, x), Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        End If
      Next sht
  Next x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are *telling* it to replace data in every cell of the entire worksheet:

```
sht.Cells.Replace
```

If you only want to replace data in columns C and D, then specify that:

```
sht.Columns("C:D").Replace
```